# Creating Assets and Subscriptions without Opportunities

Tags: cpq

TLDR: Does Salesforce only work if we use opportunities? Can an ecommerce platform push orders to Salesforce to create assets and subscriptions without going through opportunities and quotes?

We've had an implementation consultant design a Salesforce environment that I'm not entirely sure is right for us, and am trying to learn more about the platform so I can make recommendations.

We've got Woo Commerce pushing orders across, which appear against an account in SF as Orders. Then we run automation to create an Opportunity and Quote, so that we can create Assets and Contracts/Subscriptions.

Is it plausible to cut out the middleman and just create Assets and Contracts right from the order?

Comment: Out of the box, a Contract requires an Opportunity.

Comment: So in a custom build, is it possible to work around that without breaking the whole system?

Comment: While you could do that, "not breaking" essentially means reinventing a lot of the wheel. You would be getting a very poor value for the money you'd pay for SF license.